# Creating one variable from three, SPSS

Tags: syntax, spss

Cam someone be kind and help with SPSS syntax. I get error and do not understand why.
I have 3 variables:
Var1 (values 1 and 2)
Var2 (values 1 and 2)
Var3 (values 1, 2, and 3)

I want to create one variable based on these three, where values 1 on each variable ((var1=1 AND VAR2 = 1 AND Var3 = 1) is coded as 1, and all other combinations are coded as 2.

I have written this code but get error, can not understand why.

```
DO IF (Var1 = 1 AND Var2 = 1 AND Var3 = 1) COMPUTE ADL_independence_before_stroke = 1.
    IF ELSE COMPUTE ADL_independence_before_stroke = 2.
    END IF.
EXECUTE.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there but need to correct your syntax:

```
DO IF (Var1 = 1 AND Var2 = 1 AND Var3 = 1).
    COMPUTE ADL_independence_before_stroke = 1.
ELSE.
    COMPUTE ADL_independence_before_stroke = 2.
END IF.
EXECUTE.
```

And here's a shortened version:

```
compute ADL_independence_before_stroke = 2- (Var1 = 1 AND Var2 = 1 AND Var3 = 1).
```